# Kubernetes: Failed to install alpha and beta projects

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I was installing Google cloud platform on my centos 7 machine. I am reading the commands from a book and it says that I should create a Project_ID, so I put proj1, then it says that as a verification step I could type:

```
gcloud alpha projects list
```

To check the projects I have, but then I got this:

```
  $ gcloud alpha projects list
```

``ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.projects.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Project id 'proj1' not found or invalid.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - description: Google developers console
    url: https://console.developers.google.com

I thought I could skip this, so I move to the installation of kubernetes, but when I execute this script:

```
kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh
```

Now it asks also for the beta projects list. I already tried to execute the commands that it suggest:

```
gcloud alpha projects list
gcloud beta projects list
```

It shows like this

[image]

And it gives me the same error message:

[image]

Maybe there is a step in beetween, but the book didnt say anything. Can someone please assiste me? Im totally new to Kubernetes

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Errata...
Yes... I didnt double check, and there was a missing command, prior setting up the project, the command is:

```
gcloud config list project
```

and then

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```